# Response from google drive API for Node asks to use data configuration

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I would like to access Google Drive from Node app.
I am doing this tutorial from Google:  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs
However, in the listFiles method, i get this error:
'json' is not a valid configuration option. Please use 'data' instead

can anyone help?
thanks in advance
M

Answer (score 0):

i doesn't got it to work with the googleapi module
so i made the requests by my self
i tryed, and succeed with makeing the requests by my self (node https module)

[Code Example (Youtube) (Github Gist)](https://gist.github.com/hasezoey/ea84c5bbd48dcfca9d8447a1e39616dd)

(this example only works with an api key, not oauth2)

Comment: hi. thanks for your effort and sorry for my very late response. accessing Google Drive is much complex since it requires oauth2. so I can't use your solution. thanks anyway